# How to deploy war file in root(/) context to Wildfly ver 9.0.1

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly

[image: servicelog]I am newbie for Wildfly till now I was working on tomcat to deploy my applications. Now just for add on features of Wildfly we want to move on to this.
I am using Windows Os, I have done with the basic implementation of wildfly to start service etc. but Unable to deploy the ROOT.war in place of Welcome page. I have studied and gone through lot of links, I added jboss-web.xml in my project WEB-INF folder with following settings as I got in links.
But I am still unable to deploy the ROOT.war in standalone deployment. Each times it goes to failed. Not getting what I have done Wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>`
```

I have made the admin user, But for deploying I am using wildfly user setting only. For it also I uncommented the fields from bin/init.d wildfly.conf fly.
But totally unaware of the error.

**Note:** We also tried it on linux machine but ROOT.war is not getting deployed there too.[used](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/how-to-deploy-a-web-application-on-the-root-context-on-jboss-as-7)

Comment: please paste server.log of the deployment

Comment: Sir, I goin through a e-book there i got some more bat files to be executed. It would be a grd help if you can help me with this as you have worked a lot on jboss. Any mail id sir

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two files have to be added in `WEB-INF` folder before creating a war file

1. jboss-web.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
           http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
       <context-root>/</context-root>
   </jboss-web>
   ```
2. empty `bean.xml`

Comment: Still nothing for me, I hace a simple helloWorld servlet, works in tomcat but not in wildfly 9

Answer (score 24):

To override the welcome webapp with Wildfly, you need to create a `jboss-web.xml` in the `WEB-INF` of your webapp with this content:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

But if you try to access to the root directory (e.g. http://localhost:8080/) you will still have the default welcome content. To remove it, you just need to rename the directory `welcome-content` in the Wildfly directory.

Answer (score 9):

This is a solution for those using Maven in their projects. To make Wildfly host your application under `/`, you have to name the war file containing the application as "ROOT.war". To automate this action, change the default war file name in your `pom.xml` to ROOT like this:

```
...
</dependencies>
<build>
    <!-- <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName> -->
    <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
```

This way, when deploying the application to Wildfly using Maven, the file is automatically hosted in the root.

Answer (score 2):

If your web module is inside an ear you can you the following syntax

```html
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost" default-web-module="myApp.ear.myWebApp.war">
```

Answer (score 1):

The welcome page has a note at the bottom,

> To replace this page set "enable-welcome-root" to false in your server
> configuration and deploy your own war with / as its context path.

Please confirm if you did set the enable-welcome-root to false.

Comment: Sir, I am using 9.0.1 ver that don't have this property and I read somewhere that no need to do so just add jboss-web.xml in your application with context path"/".

Answer (score 1):

For my wildfly 9.0.1 deployment, we did the following two and it worked.

1. jboss-web.xml as described above by other experts.
2. In standalone.xml,

   ```
   <host name="default-host" alias="localhost, myAppDomain.com" default-web-module="myApp.war">
       <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
       <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
       <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
   </host>
   ```